# Using common set numbers in all shaders

Tags: vulkan

In Vulkan, I want to follow a convention for DescriptorSets where `set=0` contains stuff for debugging,
and `set=1` is a general set for entire frame.  Shaders may or may not use the bindings provided by these 2 sets,
depending on what they need. Shaders will, additionally, use shader-specific bindings starting at `set=2`

Shaders can be coded to use whatever set numbers. However, Pipelines expect set numbers to be 0-N. It's not
possible to tell a PSO that it uses sets 2-5; it will assume that it uses 0-3 when given the descriptor
layouts in `VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo::pSetLayouts`.

So is it the case that if I want to have that type of common set number, like set=0 being for debugging, that I have to duplicate the set layouts in all the `VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo` definitions, even if the shaders don't use those sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even if the shaders don't use those sets?

But they do use them. You put them there. They take up space.

Descriptor sets are a fiction, an agreement between your code and the Vulkan implementation that ultimately doesn't represent anything real about what the actual GPU is doing. In the hardware, there are simply sets of resources available to your pipeline. Descriptor sets abstracts the GPU's resource system.

In order to make Vulkan implementations as efficient as possible, implementations need to be able to quickly map from descriptors in a set being bound to the command buffer and the actual underlying resource mapping for those descriptors. But also, it would be useful if the user could change some resources without changing all of the currently bound ones.

To facilitate this, descriptor sets used by a pipeline and bound to the context are ordered. Set 0 gets resources first, then set 1, set 2, etc. The mapping from descriptors to resources is therefore based on the mapping for all lower-numbered descriptor sets.

For example, let's say the GPU has some array of textures that shaders can sample from. If set 0 has two texture descriptors in it, then they get array indices 0 and 1. Therefore, if set 1 has a texture descriptor in it, then that descriptor uses index 2.

The *only way* the implementation can know that set 1 uses texture index 2 is if it can see that set 0 already used two texture indices. This requires access to the layout of set 0. This applies to bind time (which is why `vkCmdBindDescriptorSets` takes a `VkPipelineLayout`), but *also* at pipeline-creation time.

Therefore, a pipeline cannot merely "use sets 2-5"; it uses *five sets*, even if it never directly accesses resources from sets 0 and 1.

Note: a lot of implementations have a limit of 4 descriptor sets. You shouldn't rely on having more, as this is the minimum Vulkan requirement.